# - -100 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Why does `signed integer overflow: 2147483647` throw:

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 - -100 cannot be represented in type 'int' on this code

```
 temp = abs(nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]-target);

 if(temp < abs(minTarget-target)){
     minTarget = nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k];
 }
```

?

Comment: An `int` has a maximum representable value. In your particular environment, `2147483647` is at or below that maximum, but `2147483647 + 100` is above it.

Comment: please show a [mre]. Are you using c or c++?

Comment: `2147483647` is the maximum value a 32-bit `int` can typically represent - adding `100` will exceed what that type can represent, causing overflow.   That is presumably what the error message you're seeing represents.  Overflow of a signed integral type has undefined behaviour.     Bear in mind that, although your compiler/system may support a 32-bit `int`,  the standard only guarantees that an `int` can represent values between `-32767` and `32767`.

Answer (score 0):

> `- -100` cannot be represented in type `int`

`- -100` is +100 and *can* be represented as an `int`.  It is the *sum* that is a problem.

`2147483647 - -100` is mathematically `2147483747`, yet that *sum* is outside OP's 32-bit `int` range of `[-2147483648 ... 2147483647]`, hence the run-time error.

---

Code could use 64-bit math to forestall overflow.  Yet the problem may remain if `minTarget` must remain `int`.

```
 long long temp = llabs(0LL + nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] - target);

 if(temp < llabs(0LL + minTarget - target)){
   minTarget = 0LL + nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k];
 }
```

`0LL + ...` insures at least 64-bit math in the addition/subtraction.